# how can i inject isolate scope into directive?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to compile a directive dynamically. This directive has an isolate scope. So something like this:

```
angular.module('mod').directive 'foo', ->
    restrict: 'E'
    templateUrl: 'foo.html'
    scope:
        text: '=text'
    bindToController: true
    replace: true
    controllerAs: 'fooCtrl'
    controller: ($scope) ->
        console.log @ # .text undefined
        console.log $scope # .text undefined
        return
```

Here is how I compile:

```
template = "<foo></foo>"
scope = $rootScope.$new()
scope.text = "hello"
$compile(template) scope, (clone, innerScope) -> 
    angular.element('body').append clone
```

However when `@` is logged, text is `undefined`. How can I pass the scope into my directive?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can pass scope into directive using link.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.text = "hello";
}
```